# Linux From Scratch Version 12.0 meson-1.2.1 Build Fails

Tags: ctypes, meson-build, linux-from-scratch

While building meson-1.2.1 in Linux From Scratch Version 12.0 at chapter 8.55, I get the following error:

```
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [72 lines of output]

# few more lines

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'
[end of output]
```

How can I build it successfully?

Answer (score 2):

The **meson-1.2.1** build fails because it can not find `_ctypes` **Python** module. After investigating the `./configure` command output for building **Python**, you can see a line stating:

> configure: WARNING: --with(out)-system-ffi is ignored on this platform

and after running `make` for **Python** you can see output saying:

```
Following modules built successfully but were removed because they could not be imported:
_ctypes
```

but we mentioned **libffi** in one of the `./configure` options:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --enable-shared --with-system-expat --with-system-ffi --enable-optimizations
```

So the root cause is in **libffi** installation that **Python** can not find it.

Going back to **libffi** `make install` output we can see it says:

```
Libraries have been installed in:
   /usr/lib/../lib64
```

but LFS at chapter 4.2 says:

> The LFS editors have deliberately decided not to use a /usr/lib64
> directory. Several steps are taken to be sure the toolchain will not
> use it. If for any reason this directory appears (either because you
> made an error in following the instructions, or because you installed
> a binary package that created it after finishing LFS), it may break
> your system. You should always be sure this directory does not exist.

So the solution is to go back and redo our work from chap 8.50 with rebuilding **libffi** and installing it in `/usr/lib/`:

```
rm /usr/lib64/libffi.*
./configure --prefix=/usr --disable-static --libdir=/usr/lib --disable-multi-os-directory --with-gcc-arch=native
```

Notice the line in `make install` output:

```
Libraries have been installed in:
   /usr/lib
```

After configuring **Python** you still get the warning but this time the `make` output doesn't mention removing `_ctypes`.